# Show Search Suggestions while typing in landscape-mode

Tags: android, landscape, search-suggestion

i already get the search suggestion while typing in the searchfield of the search-dialog. While typing in Portrait-Mode, the result are listed under the search-dialog. But when i change into landscape-mode, the text-input-field of the searchdialog becomes fullscreen (i hope you know what i mean) and the search suggestions couldn't be see anymore. i know for example from google maps that also in landscape mode the search suggestions are show under the "big" text-input-field...Wich code should i type to get this "view" while typing in landscape-mode?

Thanks!

Thomas

Comment: Can you show your layout code for that screen?

Answer (score 5):

If you want your suggestions to show up in landscape, you need to do one of the following:

- Add `SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY` to your suggestion results
- Add `android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromText"` or ``android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromData"`to your`searchable.xml`

However, I think for suggestions it's nicer to just show the normal popup instead of a fullscreen keyboard. You can achieve this by adding `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` to your `searchable.xml`.

And that's all. If you're curious, here's how I tracked this down:

[Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) will tell you that the search dialog is implemented by [`SearchDialog`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/SearchDialog.java&q=searchdialog%20package:android&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc), which uses an [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java&q=autocompletetextview%20package:android&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) for the completion text view. Its [`buildDropDown()`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java&q=autocompletetextview%20package:android&l=1235) function calls `Filter.convertResultToString()` (through [`convertSelectionToString()`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java&q=autocompletetextview%20package:android&l=838)) on the items returned by the `AutoCompleteTextView`'s `mAdapter.getItem()` and then passes these on to `InputMethodManager.displayCompletions()` (which is responsible for the suggestions you want).

In the case of `SearchDialog`, the adapter is a [`SuggestionsAdapter`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/SuggestionsAdapter.java&q=searchdialog%20package:android&d=4). This is a subclass of [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), whose `getFilter()` method returns a `CursorFilter` class, which implements [`convertResultToString()`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/CursorFilter.java&q=convertResultToString%20package:android&d=4&l=43) by just delegating to `convertToString()` on the adapter class. `SuggestionsAdapter` finally implements this method as follows:

```
public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String query = getColumnString(cursor, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY);
    if (query != null) {
        return query;
    }

    if (mSearchable.shouldRewriteQueryFromData()) {
        String data = getColumnString(cursor, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA);
        if (data != null) {
            return data;
        }
    }

    if (mSearchable.shouldRewriteQueryFromText()) {
        String text1 = getColumnString(cursor, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1);
        if (text1 != null) {
            return text1;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

…which results in the recommendations in the first paragraph above.